# Import Bitcoin price in EUR using the IMPORTXML fucntion

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml, xpath, google-finance

Hello does anybody know how to import the Bitcoin price in euro into a Google Sheets document by using the IMPORTXML function?

I am as far as I get the Bitcoin USD price -

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/";
"//span[@class='h2 text-semi-bold details-panel-item--price__value']")
```

by inspecting the CoinMarketCap site I can see the Bitcoin euro price is shown but I do not understand how to refer to it?

```
<span class="h2 text-semi-bold details-panel-item--price 
value" data-currency-value="">€3.211,55</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't be possible because button which switches between currencies is controlled by JavaScript and Google Sheets can't read JS. A workaround would be to use a different site for scraping or convert USD to EUR directly in the spreadsheet:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/";
 "//span[@class='h2 text-semi-bold details-panel-item--price__value']")
 *GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:usdeur")
```

[image]

If the **`GOOGLEFINANCE`** currency rate isn't satisfactory you can try to find a better one and **`IMPORTXML`** it too - like: **`=IMPORTXML(usd) * IMPORTXML(currency rate)`**

Comment: Thank you. I did not want to import to many data, since I think my Google Sheet becomes loaded, however it seems its the only way. Is it possible to write a function for this? I do not want to retrieve too many data at once, since I have the feeling the process of retrieving data could slow down my workbook. Anyhow, thanks for the clerification, I did not know that its controlled by an JavaScript. I thought I just need to querry differently.

Answer (score 0):

CMC change your structure. The new code to use this is:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/", "//span[@class='cmc-details-panel-price__price']")
```